# Вернуть значение при обращении к объекту

Tags: c++

Помогите, мне нужно вернуть значение если я просто обратился к объекту т.е. так

```
printf("%s", obj) //prints "some data"
```

Так как я понимаю такого оператора нет

*Методы типа `obj.getData()` не вариант*

Comment: Почитай про перегрузку оператора <<. Это как раз твой случай.

Comment: Неет не то. мне не нужно его перегружать

Comment: @evilnw изменил вопрос

Comment: Может быть вам нужно не вернуть значение, а написать оператор приведения типа ? к `const char*`, согласно вашему примеру с `printf`. Что за значение вы хотите вернуть ?

Comment: Такого оператора не просто нет, printf - это вообще C, он вообще не в курсе что там у Вас объект какого-то класса, он даже не знает ничего про классы в принципе, он видит лишь байты, а в силу формата %s будет читать их до первого нулевого и ему без разницы что там в памяти на самом деле.

Comment: Расскажите лучше, почему возникла такая необходимость. Может быть тут имеет место быть некоторое заблуждение и нужно Вам совсем иное.

Comment: Причем тут вообще printf, я его тут для примера подставил. мне необходимо что-бы при обращении к объекту вызывался метод который возвращает например массив строк.

Comment: @Duoxx в `printf` так и не получится, но вот просто в функции получится. И это единственный вариант который я вообще понимаю, а просто так на ровном месте без преобразования типов откуда вообще компилятор узнает что вы от него хотите? А вот если требуется другой тип, и у вас есть в классе оператор приведения к этому типу - тогда да.

Answer (score 6):

Использование просто имени объекта ещё не является фактом обращения к нему. Например:

```
struct S {};
S s;
sizeof(s);
```

Вычисление `sizeof(s)` происходит вовсе на этапе компиляции и опирается на статический тип объекта, переданного в качестве параметра.

Чтобы как-то фиксировать обращение к объекту нужно явно или не явно вызвать функцию, обрабатывающую объект. Пока такой функции нет, или обращение к данным идёт по другому типу (что-то подобное попытке вывести через `printf("%s")`) через какой-нибудь `cast` без привязке к виртуальным функциям, узнать об обращении к объекту не представляется возможным.

При этом допускаю, что попытки читать данные с какого-то адреса, где расположен объект, можно как-то обнаружить с помощью менеджера памяти, но эта задача уже уровня ОС, а не языка c++.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD** В ответ на комментарий. Добавил пример с функцией.

**UPD2** Список строк.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <string>


class Example{
public:
    operator int() const{
        return 5;
    }
    operator const char*() const{
        return m_text;
    }
    operator std::list<std::string>() const{
        return m_lines;
    }
private:
    const char* m_text = "5";
    const std::list<std::string> m_lines = {"1", "2", "3"};
};

void func(int d){
    std::printf("%d\n", d);
}

/*
  А вот так уже нельзя, неоднозначность, компилятор не будет знать что вы от него хотите
void func(const std::list<std::string>& l){
    for (const auto& line:l){
        printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
    }
}
*/

void funcList(const std::list<std::string>& l){
    for (const auto& line:l){
        printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
    }
}

int main()
{
    Example e;
    std::printf("%d\n", (int)e);
    std::printf("%s\n", (const char*)e);
    func(e);
    funcList(e);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чем явное преобразование в `printf` лучше упомянутого в вопросе `getData`?

Comment: @alexolut обновил пример. Явное преобразование потому-что `printf` после формата принимает список параметров, а вот когда функция принимает параметр какого-то конкретного типа, то может поможет.

Comment: Что к чему, печеньки к чаю